# How to user ImageAnalyzer to identify the hex value (RGB) of the center pixel of an image preview

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm working on a project where I need the color of the center pixel of an image preview with CameraX so I can compare it to a bank of hex values related to RGB values.

I used a short snippet with the image analyzer but it keeps crashing

```
 imageAnalyzer.setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) { image: ImageProxy ->
            // Get the center pixel of the image
            val centerX = image.width / 2
            val centerY = image.height / 2

            val bitmap = viewFinder.bitmap
            val color:Int? = bitmap?.getPixel(centerX, centerY)
            val red:Int? = color?.red
            val green:Int? = color?.green
            val blue:Int? = color?.blue
            val alpha:Int? = color?.alpha

            // Do something with the RGBA value
            Log.d("ImageAnalyzer", "RGBA: $red, $green, $blue, $alpha")

            // Close the image
            image.close()
        }
```

It leaves me with errors about the lambda set analyzer if I try to launch the camera.

EDIT: I actually used the ImageProxy object now rather than try to grab a bitmap. I also added a line in the imageAnalysis use case builder so it outputs to RGBA_8888

```
val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
    .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
    .setTargetResolution(Size(480, 640))
    .build()
```

```
imageAnalyzer.setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) { image: ImageProxy ->
    val redBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer[0].toInt()
    val greenBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer[1].toInt()
    val blueBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer[2].toInt()
    val hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", redBuffer, greenBuffer, blueBuffer)

    // Do something with the RGBA value
    Log.d("GameActivity:ImageAnalysis", "RGBA hex: $hex")

    // Close the image
    image.close()
    }


    var camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalyzer)
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
}
```

Comment: What the error are might help, but you don't seem to be actually trying to get the color of a pixel in the `image` that the `imageAnalyser` has been passed to analyse but it seems you are trying to get color of some random bitmap instead.

Comment: @Andrew How would I grab the color from the image?

Comment: How to get the color depends on the `OutputImageFormat` you set for the `imageAnalyser` which you have not shown. It's likely to be `OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_YUV_420_888` but it could be something else. I can give you an example in Java of getting the center pixel intensity value for YUV format, you would then have to get the values from the other color planes and then convert the full YUV value to RGB.

Comment: If you are using the latest alpha version, there is a ImageProxy#toBitmap API. You can convert it to Bitmap before getting the R, G and B. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageProxy#toBitmap()